# Why do Certificate Authorites cross-sign each other?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

A Certificate Authority (CA) issues digital certificates to certify the ownership of a public key by the named subject of the certificate. What is the rationale for CAs cross-signing each other (i.e. *Y* signing **Z** and **Z** signing **Y**)?

For example:

```
Let Y, X, Z be different CAs. Z may have the following signing arrangements:

    Y <<Z>>
    Z <<Y>>
    Z <<X>>
```

I couldn't find a good answer from crypto exchange; would appreciate a clear answer, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certificate Authorities cross-sign each other when they get married together.

When CA *Y* issues a certificate for CA *Z*, then any system who trusts *Y* will indirectly gain confidence in everything that *Z* issues, since, for any certificate *X* issued (signed) by *Z*, a system that trusts *Y* will build the chain *Y*→*Z*→*X*. Thus, this cross-certification represents an assertion from *Y* that basically says: "everything that *Z* signs is as good as if I, *Y*, had signed it myself".

If CA *Z* also issues a certificate for CA *Y*, then trust goes both ways. Every system that trusts either *Y* or *Z* will be able to validate certificates emitted by both. The two CA are now really one, at least as far as trust is concerned.

A *divorce* would require revoking both cross-certificates, or at least failing to issue new ones when the cross-certificates expire.

(In practice, this kind of things happens when a new CA is created but is "morally" a replacement for the old one; or when a merger occurs between two businesses and they try to fuse their internal computer systems together.)